# Conics with no real point

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, conic-sections, projective-geometry, affine-geometry

When my professor was going through coninc sections of the real plane he didn't really mention why such a curve has no real points iff the determinant of the matrix associated to the conic, ***A***, without the first row and column is positive (this I get it, of course, it has to be an ellipse) and ***a(1,1) • det A > 0***.

The second part is the one that messes me up: I've been trying to understand why it works this way for the last three days, unsuccessfully. Could someone show me a proof? My books don't even talk about it and I haven't found much on the web so far.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Ponder the equation $x^2+y^2+1=0.$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: I know that every imaginary ellipse can assume that form in a specific frame of reference but i really don't understand how the property I wrote should still hold

Comment: What is your convention for the associated matrix to $ax^2+2bxy+cy^2+2dx+2ey+f$. Is it $\begin{pmatrix}f& e&d\\e&c&b\\d&b&a \end{pmatrix}$ ?

Comment: Exactly that one for we distinguish proper and improper points from the first (the 0th) component of their position vector.

Comment: Can one say that your criteria is: $a(1,1)>0$ **and** $\det(A)>0$ where $\det(A)=ca-b^2$ ? Or do you involve also the big determinant ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is something slightly different from your criterion.

Using homogeneous coordinates $(x,y,t)$:

$$X^TAX=\begin{pmatrix}t&y&x \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}f& e&d\\e&c&b\\d&b&a \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}t\\y\\x \end{pmatrix}\tag{1}$$

(think to $t=1$ for "ordinary points")

Saying that this conic has no real points is the same as saying it remains always positive or always negative. See appendix for that.

Let us assume, up to a multiplication by $-1$ of matrix $A$ that we are in the first case ($\forall X, \ X^TAX > 0$). It means that $A$ is a **positive definite matrix**.

A classical necessary and sufficient condition for a matrix to be positive definite is [Sylvester's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_criterion):  either that:

$$f>0 \  \ \ \& \ \ \ \begin{vmatrix}f& e\\e&c \end{vmatrix}>0 \  \ \ \& \ \ \ \begin{vmatrix}f& e&d\\e&c&b\\d&b&a \end{vmatrix}>0$$

or / and (going from bottom right to upper left):

$$a>0 \  \ \ \& \ \ \ \begin{vmatrix}c& b\\b&a \end{vmatrix}>0 \  \ \ \& \ \ \ 
 \begin{vmatrix}f& e&d\\e&c&b\\d&b&a \end{vmatrix}>0$$

You see that we are not far from your criterion...

---

**Appendix:** By contradiction, assume that for certain $X_1, X_2 \in \mathbb{R^3}$, we have simultaneously

$$X_1^TAX_1<0 \ \ \text{and} \ \ X_2^TAX_2>0$$

then, setting $X=\lambda X_1+X_2$, expanding

$$X^TAX=(\lambda X_1+X_2)^TA(\lambda X_1+X_2)$$

$$=(X_1^TAX_1)\lambda^2 + 2(X_1^TAX_2)\lambda  + X_2^TAX_2$$

The discriminant of this quadratic in $\lambda$

$$\Delta=4((X_1^TAX_2)^2-(X_1^TAX_1)(X_2^TAX_2))$$

being $>0$, there exists a real root $\lambda$ giving a solution $X \in \mathbb{R^3}$ to $X^TAX=0$.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, it already is a big help for me. Just one thing: how can the fact that XTAX/=0 for all Xs imply that XTAX<0 or XTAX>0 for all Xs? In general, shouldn't that implication be true only for some Xs?

Comment: Indeed, there was a gap in my proof. See the appendix I just added.

Comment: Are now OK with this question ?

Comment: Oh, yes! I'm positive with it even if I'm not familiar woth the theorem. I wasn't writing anything because I read that short answers without meaningful content should have been avoided. Thanks so much for your very important help!

Comment: Thanks for your thanks!